# html and javascript password: how to change display of an element if the password is correct?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a password protected image in HTML with help of Javascript, which means, if you enter a correct password, an image would appear.I'm a beginner, so I can't find any error in this. I don't even know if any if this code is well written, so I would be very thankful if you could help.

**HTML:**

```
    <img src="..." id="smiley"/>
     <form>
         This picture is password protected<br>Enter a password:<br>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
         <input type="button" onclick="funcPass( );" value="Ok">
     </form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    var password = getElementById("password").value;
    function funcPass(password.value) {
        if (password.value == "smiley")
        {
            document.getElementById("smiley").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            password.value = " ";
        }
     }
```

In **CSS** I changed image display property to none

Comment: Hi Sara, is that password something static of is it coming out of a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code to get the password needs to be in the function itself. You're also getting the value twice (the value of the value). Try this:

```
function funcPass() {
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (password == "In A Darkened Room")
    {
        document.getElementById("smiley").style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        password = "";
    }
 }
```

Comment: `var password = event.target.value` wont work since `event.target` is the button and not the password field

Comment: I'd also suggest storing the element in `password` instead of the actual value, `password = ""` accomplishes nothing. I'm assuming the point is to clear the field, in which case it would be `password.value = ""`

Comment: the `password` variable refers to the value, not the element

Comment: That was my point, `password` *should* refer to the element instead of being a copy of the value

Comment: The `else {}` logic does nothing in this example. You're clearing a temporary variable.

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

1. Your variable `password` is declared outside of your function, so it doesn't need to be passed as a parameter.
2. I changed your `password` variable to just contain a reference to the `#password` element itself, so you can get its value as it changes later.
3. Changed `getElementById` to `document.getElementById` to stop it from throwing an error.

Here's a functional demo:

```js
var password = document.getElementById("password");

function funcPass() {
  if (password.value == "In A Darkened Room") {
    document.getElementById("smiley").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    password.value = "";
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="..." id="smiley" />
<form>
  This picture is password protected<br>Enter a password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <input type="button" onclick="funcPass();" value="Ok">
</form>
```